# Viewflipper in android not flipping all the time

Tags: android, viewflipper, ads

I have two views (ads) and when one ad network has no ad to show the view is supposed to flip to admob as a backup.  The first view is inmobi (not sure if that has any relevance).  If I force the inmobi ad to fail by turning test ads on the view will flip and show the admob ad but when live ads are turned on, the view never flips even when the failed ad callback is received.  Please help.

```
@Override
public void adRequestFailed(InMobiAdView arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("","inmobi ad request failed");

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    loadAdmob();
    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ads);

    vf.showNext();
}

private void loadAdmob() {

    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxx");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

}
```

And the XML

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ads"
    android:layout_width="320dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip">

    <LinearLayout
           android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <com.inmobi.androidsdk.impl.InMobiAdView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id = "@+id/adview"
     />
     </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout" ></LinearLayout>

    </ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no see the question yet. But if you need to flip just between Layouts I can provide my own code how to use the flip functionality. First you should create a separate pages of your future Layouts, like **page_1.xml** in res.layout folder.

```
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@color/GreenColor"
  >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="120dip">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

After you have done, describe a **main.xml** file including external xml-pages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <include android:id="@+id/libraryView1"  layout="@layout/page_1" />
    <include android:id="@+id/libraryView2"  layout="@layout/page_2" />
    <include android:id="@+id/libraryView3"  layout="@layout/page_3" />
</ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Than don't forget in class file to declare vf=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
Next step you should to override OnTouchEvent to calculate new coordinates and showing the flip-animation:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                oldTouchValueX = touchevent.getX();
                oldTouchValueY = touchevent.getY();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                //if(this.searchOk==false) return false;
                float currentX = touchevent.getX();
                float currentY = touchevent.getY();

                float deltaX = getAbs(oldTouchValueX - currentX);
                float deltaY = getAbs(oldTouchValueY - currentY);

                if (deltaX >= deltaY)
                {
                    if (oldTouchValueX < currentX)
                    {
                        vf.setInAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation());
                        vf.setOutAnimation(outToRightAnimation());
                        vf.showNext();
                    }
                    if (oldTouchValueX > currentX)
                    {
                        vf.setInAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
                        vf.setOutAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
                        vf.showPrevious();
                    } 
                } //if deltaX
                else
                    {
                    if (oldTouchValueY < currentY)
                    {
                        vf.setInAnimation(inFromUpAnimation());
                        vf.setOutAnimation(outToDownAnimation());
                        vf.showNext();

                    }
                    if (oldTouchValueY > currentY)
                    {
                        vf.setInAnimation(inFromDownAnimation());
                        vf.setOutAnimation(outToUpAnimation());
                        vf.showPrevious();
                    }
                } //Else
            break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And the last one - describe an animation methods which mentioned in OnTouchEvent:

```
public static Animation inFromRightAnimation() 
{
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  +1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    inFromRight.setDuration(350);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}

public static Animation outToLeftAnimation() 
{
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  -1.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,  0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,   0.0f
    );
    outtoLeft.setDuration(350);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoLeft;
}
```

Write similar for the rest in/out flip directions.